# Как называются обращения через :: в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Немного туповатый вопрос. Я новичок в Laravel Framework, которому нужно максимально быстро освоить Laravel.
Немного не понимаю обращения через :: .
Например,

```
  'code' => Str::upper(Str::random(5)),
  $booking = Booking::create($bookingData);
  'flights_back' => FlightResource::collection($flightsBack),
  return Passengers::where('document_number', $this->document_number)->count();
```

Помогли бы ссылки на литературу где можно почитать от этом. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-> оператор обращения к обьекту класса

:: оператор обращения к самому классу ( к примеру к статическим переменым и методам)